# Web "Copy to Clipboard" without triggering mobile keyboards

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

This JavaScript copies the intended text to the user's clipboard on both desktop and mobile browsers. However on mobile browsers it triggers the phone's keyboard to pop up.

It operates by getting a string from an HTML input and is initiated by an HTML button.

Here I input and define the value and ID it.

```
<input type="text" value="THIS GETS COPIED" id="CopyThis">
```

The ID gets passed along to the function which copies it to the clipboard.

```
function copy() {
var copyText = document.getElementById("CopyThis");
copyText.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

This HTML button initiates the function.

```
<button onclick="copy();">
```

Is there an alternative method to copying a string of text to a clipboard that doesn't trigger a phone's keyboard on mobile browsers?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify that the input field is read-only:

```
<input type="text" value="THIS GETS COPIED" id="CopyThis" readonly>
```

This will prevent the mobile keyboard to trigger

Answer (score 1):

hide the field once you are done with copying the data.

```
function copy() {
var copyText = document.getElementById("CopyThis");
copyText.select();
document.execCommand("copy");

setTimeout(function() {
        copyText.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: This was really useful to me. I have a page that I want to copy some details with, and navigator.clipboard.writeText doesn't work on mobile or chromeOS. I don't want a random textarea making the page ugly just for a select and copy, so I used display:none on the dom element by default and then the js changes it to display:inline, selects and copies, and then switches it back to display:none. It happens so fast, the user never sees the textarea.